# Confirming function calls inside a function I'm unittesting with mock module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function I'm writing unit tests for.  I'm trying to assert that a number of functions were called with the proper arguments given the input argument.  For example, the function I'm unit testing is in a file called validate.py

```
def function_to_test(arg1):
    print 'return2: ', _sub_function_1()
    arg1 = _sub_function_1(arg1)
    arg1 = _sub_function_2(arg1)
    arg1 = _sub_function_3(arg1)
    return arg1


def _sub_function_1(arg1):
    pass

def _sub_function_2(arg1):
    pass

def _sub_function_3(arg1):
    pass
```

I have my unit tests in a file called dotest.py,

```
import validate
import unittest
import mock

class TestFunctionToTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('validate._sub_function_1')
    def test_basic(self, m_sub_function_1):
        m_sub_function_1 = mock.Mock(return_value='rv_sf1')
        dum_arg1 = 'dum'
        out = validate.function_to_test(dum_arg1)
        print 'called?: ', m_sub_function_1.called

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The results of running this test are,

```
run -i dotest.py
return2:  <MagicMock name='_sub_function_1()' id='4502266128'>
called?:  False
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

For some reason the return value defined for the mock function is not being recognized in the call to `_sub_function_1`.  I want to check if this function is actually called in `function_to_test`.  Any insight from the mock gurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `self` argument seems to be missing in your `test_basic`. Furthermore, your code doesn't call `function_to_test`. Personally I write the argument to `mock.patch` as a string so it would become:

```
class TestFunctionToTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('validate._sub_function_1')
    def test_basic(self, m_sub_function_1):
        m_sub_function_1.return_value = 'rv_sf1'
        function_to_test(...)
```

This should print: `return2: rv_sf1`. You can then assert it has been called with the correct arguments:

```
m_sub_function1.assert_called_with(...)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The errors you spotted were due to me making mistakes in translating my complicated problem to a simpler test case.  I still get the result that my return value is not recognized in the line with "return2".  Maybe I've missed something in translating the problem to a minimal example.  Let me code this up and see if it works.

Comment: I have confirmed that my minimal example still does not produce the proper return value. I will edit the post to reflect the exact code I'm using

Comment: @Gabriel: have you tried the exact example above? You shouldn't replace the mock that you're given as argument within the unit test, you should modify it according to your needs. Otherwise you're only modifying a local variable.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code in my post, I get exactly the output I've shown.  Do you get something different?

Comment: @Gabriel: the code in your post doesn't do the same thing as the above answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I should not define the m_sub_function_1 as a mock object inside the function test_basic, it has that property when it is passed in as an argument.

Comment: @Gabriel: yes, when using `mock.patch` is already gets mocked and it's passed as an argument to the test function. So reassigning to it won't change the mock object that will be used. That's why you need to modify the given argument.